# inserting multiple copies of the same component in the Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am learning Angular using the "Tour of Heroes" app. In the [multiple components part](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html), we can show hero details by clicking on the hero name. What would be the design pattern (or implementation) to have multiple instances of "Hero Details" component, so it is displayed dynamically under each hero, when it is clicked?

```
template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
      (click)="onSelect(hero)">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
`
```

My goal is to have "my-hero-detail" element in each "li" and then display it with that specific hero details upon clicking on the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<my-hero-detail>` multiple times:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i=index"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="selectedHeroes[i] = !selectedHeroes[i]">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="hero" [style.display]="selectedHeroes[i] ? 'block' : 'none'"></my-hero-detail>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then if you want to be able to hide/show the detail you have to update `selectedHeroes` to contain true/false values for each hero indicating whether it should be visible or not.

```
selectedHeroes: Object = {};
```

See demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nG0RkwR2kmr6AXzln6mU?p=info

Note that styles are mangled because `<li>` doesn't expect to contain `<my-hero-detail>` elements.

Comment: I think your example here is missing "let i=index", but overall thanks! This and "[hero]="hero" were the two parts I could not figure out on my own.